# Generating a list of random numbers, then sorting them

Tags: python, sorting

New to python and understanding the logic of a small program but a bit stuck. Here's what I am trying to do.

I want the program to generate 5 random numbers, then sort them in order using a bubble sort. Then the user needs to enter in 5 numbers in any order and the program will say whether it's in there or not.

Here's what I've done so far.

```
import random

def randomNum()
    list = []
    list.append(random.sample(range(1, 100), 5))
    print list
```

First days of python so I've messed up a little here syntax-wise but can't see what's wrong at first with the number generation function.

Then, here's what I'd do to bubble sort that.

```
def bubble(list):
    length = len(list) - 1
    unsorted = True
    while unsorted:
        unsorted = False
        for element in range(0,length):
            #unsorted = False
            if badList[element] > list[element + 1]:
                 hold = list[element + 1]
                 list[element + 1] = list[element]
                 list[element] = hold
                 unsorted = True
                 print list
             else:
                 unsorted = True

     return list
```

After that, not sure how I can get input and compare it to see if it's in that list. Here's what I have so far.

Any pointers?

Comment: You can take input using: `feedback = raw_input("Please enter something? :")` `print feedback`

Comment: Do not use `list` as a name, because it shadows the Python builtin `list()`.

Comment: `randomNum()` has a number of flaws... 1) a function _usually_ `return`s an object, yours doesn't.  2) `random.sample()` returns a list, so that you have no need for an outer list. 3) it would be better to pass arguments into the function.  4) all in all, you could as well call directly `random.sample()`.

Comment: Thanks for the small pointers and I've corrected that first bit. Still working on the rest

Answer (score 0):

### How to get input

Use `raw_input()` (Python 2) or `input()` (Python 3).  Never use `input()` in Python 2 because it is a serious security issue.

#### Generic solution

If you're writing a module that uses user's input and is to be used with both Python versions, you can use Python's `try ... except` mechanism

```
try:
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    pass
...
answer = input('Which is smaller, 3 or 4? ')
```

### Input treatment

Note that `input()` returns a `string`, i.e., a sequence of characters, so it is possible that you want to further process the `answer` if you need a numerical value for the following computations

```
answer = input('Which is smaller, 3 or 4? ')
min_squared = answer**2
```

```
answer = input('Which is smaller, 3 or 4? ')
answer = int(answer)
min_squared = answer**2
```

To this purpose you use the `int()` builtin, as in the example above, or `float()` if you need a floating point number.

### How to check for inclusion

If you want to check if an element is contained in a container, you shall use the `in` operator,

```
 if 4 in [1,2,3,4,5]: print('Found!')
 ...
 if int(answer) in sorted_list:
     print('You win!')
```

#### Warning

Python offers you different type of containers, `list`'s `tuple`'s `dict`'s and `set`'s.  Some of these are optimized for testing inclusion (namely `dict`'s and `set`'s) while the others have to be scanned, element by element, to check for inclusion.

While this issue is not relevant in your case, if you had to check for inclusion some thousands of items against a list of millions of items, using a `set` instead of a `list` for the container leads to much, much better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I want to show you full code, and I will make comments later:

```
import random


def randomNum():
    return random.sample(range(1, 100), 5)

numbers_list = randomNum()
# print numbers_list

for _ in xrange(5):
    num = int(raw_input())
    if num in numbers_list:
        print "%d is in the list" % num
    else:
        print "There is no %d in the list" % num
```

Now step by step:

**1** :

```
def randomNum():
    return random.sample(range(1, 100), 5)
```

Here we create list of 5 random numbers and then return it (we will need it later, so we use `return` instead or `print`). random.sample is list itself so we don't need to append it anywhere, because we will have structure like [[1,2,3]] and it's not what we want.

**2** :

```
numbers_list = randomNum()
# print numbers_list
```

Here we create a list of random numbers, generated by `randomNum()`

**3** :

```
for _ in xrange(5):
    num = int(raw_input())
    if num in numbers_list:
        print "%d is in the list" % num
    else:
        print "There is no %d in the list" % num
```

For 5 times we take a user number and check if it's in the list. We use `in`. I think it's easy to understand what `in` does. If num in list we print that `num is in the list`, otherwise we print `num isn't in the list`

**5** :

We don't use sort here, because `in` doesn't need list to be shuffled.

Comment: no no no, please do not use `list` as a name, it is a builtin (try `print list(1,2,3,4)` in the interpreter) and you'd better leave it alone.

Comment: @gboffi ah, yes, you are right, i just played with his solution and didn't change it. Thank you.